# Sql Server: culture changed once i moved to another server. c# .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, decimal, culture

Recently I decided to move to another server. Now my application runs on different servers with different culture (IT and EN).

Everything worked fine but now i am facing many problems with date and numbers.

The main problem seems to be SQL Server. In fact, SQL SERVER throws errors. 
I solved the problem with date using the method ParseExact:

```
   e.Command.Parameters["@Expiry"].Value = 
             DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/2099", "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

For decimal numbers i have to swap "." and "," (depending of the culture) if i want the application to work:

```
   Latitude.Value = Latitude.Value.Replace(".", ","); //ONLY for ITALIAN CULTURE
   e.Command.Parameters["@Latitude"].Value = Latitude.Value;
```

I repeat: the errors are generated by SqlServer.
Is there any way to set the culture once for all?

PS: the EN server is GoDaddy Hosting.

***UPDATE:***
The problem is pure Sql Server.
In fact, checking on my servers, I found a ',' on the first one and a '.' on the second one as separators for money and decimals.I found:
        ALTER LOGIN 'MYDBLOGIN' WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = Italian; GO

With the previous query i was able to change the culture on sql server. However, the problem is still there.

Comment: Is this code running within a CLR object? If not, I don't see how C# code can "fix" an SQL Server error.

Comment: you can set culture using global.asax or also you can set SQL SERVER Collate

Comment: Are you storing dates in SQL as *char, or one of the date data types?

Comment: The problem is pure Sql Server.

In fact, checking on my servers, I found a ',' on the first one and a '.' on the second one as separators for money and decimals. I found:

ALTER LOGIN 'MYDBLOGIN' WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = Italian; GO

With the previous query i was able to change the culture on sql server. However, the problem is still there.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: In fact c# can't help.

Comment: @nonnb: datetime and decimal.

Comment: @user1589910: Is it multilingual website ??, If yes then you need to set datetime according to the culture. `DateTime myDate;
        DateTime.TryParse(yourdate, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate);`

Answer (score 0):

What does this return?

```
 select @@LANGID, @@LANGUAGE
```

If it says Italian,

```
 set language us_english
```

(or whatever...)

Comment: Thank you. However, I have just found the right query:

ALTER LOGIN 'MYDBLOGIN' WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = Italian;
GO

Answer (score 0):

Rather than every time changing the SQL server culture why don't you use

```
   Convert.ToDecimal(Latitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: well, that is what i am gonna do. But i have many lines of code to change. Much better if i could change just the culture of DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime myDate;
 DateTime.TryParse(yourdate, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate);
```

Or

```
 DateTime datet1=new DateTime(2012,5,1);
 string startdate = datet1.ToString("d", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

You can change your database Collate:

```
ALTER DATABASE test2 -- put your database name here
   COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS   -- replace with whatever collation you need
```

Your problem is not of sqlserver,  you make you modifed in your code while inserting/fetching datetime according to the CultureInfo